# Concatenate many rows into one signle row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM users 
GROUP BY sum ASC
```

I want to get all sums where smaller sums are first in one string. With the query above, I get all the sums (many rows) and with the correct ordering. If I user `ORDER BY` instead, I get one string, but it doesn't have the correct ordering. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `order by` to `group_concat` to specify the ordering within a group:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY sum DESC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM    users
```

Comment: Amazing! But I guess I don't need the last `GROUP BY sum ASC`.

Comment: @evening: You're right, with `group by sum` you'd get a row for each value of `sum`